# Kotlin, string template with properties

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin. I have the following code:

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String) {

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person("Tonj", "Manero")
    println("Hello, world! ${p.name}")
}
```

This code does not work, it give an error during compilation. The question is: how can i use a property value in a string template in Kotlin? Tnx

Comment: also see [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Comment: There is actually no need for a data class in this case, just properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are declaring constructor arguments, not properties. You have to declare them as `val` or `var`.

```
class Person(val name: String, val surname: String) {

}
```

If you leave off the `val` or `var`, Kotlin treats them as arguments to the constructor itself. They would be available for use in any field initializers or init blocks, but they won't be declared as properties.